# Variable dumpper template function doesn't respect scope

Tags: d

I have a handy `dump` function (copied from internet, most likely from https://forum.dlang.org/) that I'm using to investigate variables.

I just noticed it doesn't respect scopes in all cases (see below). Why and how I can fix it to get the expected results ? Or is the function fundamentally flawed ? `dump` has been very valuable when I have been learning D.

I'm using DMD64 D Compiler v2.083.0 on Linux.

Expected results when compiled with `-debug`:

```
(immutable(int) x = 1)
(immutable(immutable(char)[]) x = A)
(immutable(double) x = 1.1)
```

but instead got:

```
(immutable(int) x = 1)
(immutable(int) x = 1)
(immutable(double) x = 1.1)
```

The code:

```
void dump(alias variable)()
{
  import std.stdio : writefln;
  writefln("(%s %s = %s)",
           typeid(typeof(variable)),
           variable.stringof,
           variable);
}

void main()
{
  {
    immutable x = 1; debug dump!x;
  }

  {
    immutable x = "A"; debug dump!x;
  }

  {
    void f() { immutable x = 1.1; debug dump!x; }
    f();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you ran into this compiler bug:

https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13617

> function-local symbols do not have unique names and conflict with symbols in sibling scopes

A minimal example derived from the bug report to illustrate the issue:

```
bool isInt(alias x)() { return is(typeof(x) == int); }

void main() {
  { int   a; static assert(isInt!a); }
  { float a; static assert(isInt!a); } // passes unexpectly (compiler bug)
}
```

The code above incorrectly compiles even the second `static assert` should fail compile time.